# What's the area of this interior shape within $x+y=10$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area

Let $x+y=10$ and join each of these $(x,y)$ coordinate pairs with a line

```
(0,10) - (0,0)
(0,9)  - (1,0)
(0,8)  - (2,0)
...
(8,0)  - (0,2)
(9,0)  - (0,1)
(10,0) - (0,0)
```

It starts to form this shape

[image: area_shape]

Letting the number of $(x,y)$ points tend to infinity yields

[image: shape_inf]

It's not a circle because completing it shows this

[image: not_a_circle]

What's the area of that green shape?

Comment: One fourth of the green section could be an [astroid](https://mathimages.swarthmore.edu/index.php/Envelope). See figure $1.3$

Comment: The area is $(3\pi a^2)/8$ with $a=10$ is $117.81$ from this source https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_inside_Astroid

Comment: The curve is also called a quadratic [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve), appearing in [string arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_art) or curve stitching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The curve is $$|y|=(a^k-|x|^{k})^{1/k}, k<1, x\in[-a,a]$$
For $k=1/2$ it is $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}=\sqrt{a}$ it is a parabola all   quadrants touching both x and y axis. For $k=1$ it is a square, for $k=2$ it is circle. for $k>2$ it will be a closed figure like circle. For $k>>2$. it will be a square with rounded edges. for $k\to \infty$ is will be square with corners as $(\pm a, \pm a)$.
You may also write the Eq, of this curve as
$|x|^k+|y|^k=a^k$ for your first curve $k<1$ and for the second $k>2$.
For %a=1$ and $k=1/2,1,2,4$, see the curves below:

[image]